# How to determine if endpoint routing is enabled at runtime ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am converting some of my old ASP.Net Core applications from 2.1 to 3.1.

I know how to use `options.EnableEndpointRouting = false` to use the legacy IRouter logic; however, once I have set this, is there a flag built into ASP.Net that I can read to tell the current value of `EnableEndpointRouting`?

I currently call `UseMvc` from a completely different place from where I set `EnableEndpointRouting` with `AddMvc`, and I want to be able to decide whether to use `UseMvc` or `UseEndpoints` once I get there.

If you are wondering why I want this to even be switchable, it is part of a framework that I maintain, so the applications do not simply hard code these things inside Startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want to do the value control? In general you can inject `MvcOptions` and get the value from it.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IOptions<MvcOptions> _ops;

    public Foo(IOptions<MvcOptions> ops)
    {
        _ops = ops;
    }

    public bool IsEndPointRoutingEnabled => _ops.Value.EnableEndpointRouting;
}
```

#### Update

If you want to use `GetService` instead of injection to the constructor:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IOptions<MvcOptions> _ops;

    public Foo(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _ops = provider.GetService(typeof(IOptions<MvcOptions>)) as IOptions<MvcOptions>;
    }

    public bool IsEndPointRoutingEnabled => _ops.Value.EnableEndpointRouting;
}
```

> Notice that this is considered as anti-pattern and [not recommended when using DI is applicable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#recommendations)

Comment: does this actually work for you?  I tried accessing the options with GetService<MvcOptions>, but that returned null.  I even added .AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions>(options) to my AddMvc call to make sure the options are captured, but GetService still returns null.

Comment: @Eric yes it works for me, I've updated the answer to show how to use with `GetService` pattern.

Comment: that is what I was missing.  I had neglected to include IOptions around the MvcOptions type when requesting the service.  Thank you.